# script to match software Powershell

Tags: powershell, compareobject

```
Write-Host "Missing Software listed below..." -ForegroundColor Red 

if ($Zbook){
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $SLZ -DifferenceObject $SLAcutal -Property DisplayName -PassThru | 
    Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | 
    Select-Object DisplayName | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders 
} 
Else{
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $SLS -DifferenceObject $SLAcutal -Property DisplayName -PassThru | 
    Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | 
    Select-Object DisplayName | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
}
```

This is my first script, Idealy, I would only like the write-host "missing software..." to be presented if compare ref. object doesn't match difference object. and "missing software" if matches

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're missing some information... What are you comparing?  How are you defining `$SLZ` and `$SLS`?

Comment: You likely want an `if(){}else{}` statement to accomplish that

Comment: I created variables for $SLZ, $SLS, & $SLActual.